# session does not work with htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created a MVC php script where all requests are done in one page (main.php) and that page invoke the controller based on the `module` passed in the query string.

To make the url pretty, I used htaccess and wrote the ff.:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ main.php?module=news/index [QSA]
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?module=news/view&id=$1&slug=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^login$ main.php?module=login/index [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ main.php?module=user/view&slug=$1 [QSA,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(css|js|jpg|png|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main.php?module=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now, session suddenly does not work.
When I log in successfully, the page is redirected http://domain.com/

From there I can see that the session is registered properly but after I reload the page, I'm logged out again like the session only worked for the current page. And not on the next page.

I had done the ff but none of it fixed my problem:

1. session.auto_start

   `ini_set('session.auto_start',1)`
2. session.bug_compat (As posted in SO)

   `ini_set('session.bug_compat_42', 0);`

   `ini_set('session.bug_compat_warn', 0);`
3. to make sure session works for in subdomains

   `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.mydomain.tld');`
4. session_start() -> always present in my page
5. session.save_path is rewriteable
6. all request is sent to domain.com not www.domain.com
7. The session key I used to save and get data is correct

I'm pretty sure problem is with my htaccess cause before it, my script is working fine with session.

Please, I would appreciate it if anyone can help. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think your mod_rewrite rules have anything to do with your problem with sessions. The `session.cookie_domain` howover can be critical if misconfigured.

Comment: Why do you set `session.auto_start` using `ini_set()` instead of calling `session_start()`? I think your problem lies here.

Comment: It's quite possible that something wrong is with your code. What do you put into `$_SESSION`? How do you check if user is logged? What's the `$_SESSION` value when use is logged out?

Comment: @Havenard even without that and I'm just using `session_start`, session still does not work :(

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I use `$_SESSION['sess_user_id']`. That where I save and get the value currently logged in user. `sess_user_id` is null when user is logged out.